# Force application to use NIC (without access to underlying socket)

Tags: c++, nic

I have a third-party API that makes a TCP connection to an external server. I do not have access to the underlying socket behind the TCP connection.

I have built an application that uses this API. On my machine, I want to run two instances of this application. My machine has two network interfaces. I want the first instance of my application to use the first network interface and I want the second instance of my application to use the second network interface. I cannot figure out how to do this without having access to the underlying socket. I am working in a linux environment.

Comment: Yes but are you working in a programming environment?

Comment: Yes. I am using C++.

Comment: You should include the language you are using in the tags. That way you can attract people who monitor questions with the c++ tag.